# \DeclareMathSymbol with Pazo Math Blackboard Bold (from Mathpazo)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, mathpazo

I want to create a mnemonic command for `\mathbb{1}` as provided by `mathpazo`. I can't just use `\newcommand*{\unity}{\mathbb{1}}`, because that would break the moment I were to change math fonts (e.g., if I wanted to revert to Computer Modern), since usually there is not `\mathbb{1}` provided and I would need to load a package like `bbm`.

So instead I thought I could use `\DeclareMathSymbol{\unity}{\mathord}{<sym-font-name}{<slot>}`. But how can I find the proper `family` in `\DeclareSymbolFont{sym-font-name}{encoding}{family}{series}{shape}`?

[pazotest.pdf](http://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathpazo/pazotest.pdf) on page 12 states that apparently the slot for `\mathbb{1}` is `"31`, but I don't know how to access "Pazo Math Blackboard Bold".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{fplmbb}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
  $\mathbb{1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

You can declare a new math alphabet `\mathbb` and you have access to it without loading `mathpazo`. The downside is clearly this occupy a math alphabet (out of the limited 16). Another solution which is perhaps more close to what you want is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{PazoBB}{U}{fplmbb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\unity}{\mathord}{PazoBB}{"31}
\begin{document}
  $\unity$
\end{document}
```

The point is that you need to find out the encoding, font family name, etc of the Pazo Math font. And these can be found through looking into `mathpazo.sty` if you want more details

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is what I wanted. Next time, I will directly look at that .sty file. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to waste a math-alphabet, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bbm}

\newcommand*{\unity}{\textrm{{\usefont{U}{fplmbb}{m}{n}1}}}

\begin{document} 
\[
\unity , \mathbbm{R}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use amsmath, it would be better to use `\text` instead of `\textrm`.