# Is there an easy way to use only mathpazo's blackboard-bold facilities (without it using Palatino)?

Tags: fonts, mathpazo, blackboard

The `mathpazo` package sets Palatino as the document's main font. However I am only interested in its blackboard bold symbols. Is there an easy way for me to only use Mathpazo's bb symbols?

Comment: Possibly the first answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56299/14100) will help out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following example adds the relevant code of package `mathpazo` for `\mathbb`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mathbb\relax
  \DeclareMathAlphabet\PazoBB{U}{fplmbb}{m}{n}%
  \newcommand{\mathbb}{\PazoBB}%
}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: \mathbb of mathpazo]